# how to get height of the camera lens from the ground?

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I want to get height from ground level to the camera lens.Can any one suggest me a method to do this.I have Google it but could not find any solution even mathematical formula too.

Comment: Instruct the user to drop the camera and time how long it takes to hit the ground.

Comment: (You need something in the view that will give you SOME dimension.  This could be autofocus info, or the size of some object in the image.  But without some sort of hard dimension to start with there's no way to calculate height.)

Answer (score 0):

pythagorean theorem is the formula you are looking for.

No idea how you might get the values to use it though, other than if there is a way to determine the distance from the camera to what it is focusing on would get you one. If you can do that, they can just point it at the ground/tap to focus and give you the height.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem can be a applied for a right angled triangle only.Here in this case device can be tilted .I was able to obtain the tilted angle .